# Can I limit pmouseX/pmouseY in p5js?

Tags: p5.js

I have this blob in the middle of the screen, and when the user moves the mouse, the blob moves along. I'm trying to limit that movement. I want my blob to move only 30px to the left/right/bottom/top. Is it possible? Here is my code:

```
  xposition = pmouseX === 0 ? windowWidth/2 : pmouseX
  yposition = pmouseY === 0 ? windowHeight/2: pmouseY
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that come to my mind:

1. You can map your width and height to -30px ...30px

   let xpos = map(mouseX, 0, width, width/2-30, width/2+30);
2. You can just do:

   xpos = Math.floor(windowWidth/2-mouseX) > 30 ? windowWidth/2 : mouseX

This should work with both `pmouseX` and `mouseX` but I'm curious, why are you using `pmouseX` instead of current frame `mouseX`?

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the values with `min()` and `max()` functions:

```
  xposition = pmouseX === 0 ? windowWidth/2 : max(min(pmouseX,30),-30)
  yposition = pmouseY === 0 ? windowHeight/2: max(min(pmouseY,30),-30)
```

or with `constrain()` function:

```
xposition = pmouseX === 0 ? windowWidth/2 : constrain(pmouseX, -30, 30)
yposition = pmouseY === 0 ? windowHeight/2: constrain(pmouseY, -30, 30)
```